# Configure one-to-one mapping EF code first with different column names. Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities:

```
public partial class Web_Vendor
{  
    public string VendorID { get; set; }
    public virtual Deal_Brands DealBrand { get; set; }
}
 public partial class Deal_Brands
 {    
    public string Brand { get; set; }    
    public virtual Web_Vendor WebVendor { get; set; }    
 }
```

I need to configure one-to-one mapping using fields `VendorID <-> Brand` using fluent API.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Web_Vendor>().HasOptional(x=>x.DealBrand).WithRequired(x=>x.WebVendor).
                Map(x=>x.MapKey(""))
```

Can anyone help to continue this line?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your classes I see that the relationship between `Web_Vendor` and `Deal_Brands` is "one-to-zero-one" (1-0.1) not "one-to-one". It means that `Deal_Brands` primary key must be the `Web_Vendor` primary key. The classes would be something like this:

```
public partial class Web_Vendor
{  
    public string VendorID { get; set; }
    public virtual Deal_Brands DealBrand { get; set; }
}
 public partial class Deal_Brands
 {    
    public string VendorID { get; set; }   
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public virtual Web_Vendor WebVendor { get; set; }    
 }
```

The mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Web_Vendor>()
    .HasKey(i => i.VendorID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Deal_Brands>()
    .HasKey(i => i.VendorID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Web_Vendor>()
     .HasOptional(x=>x.DealBrand)
     .WithRequired(x=>x.WebVendor);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It's really good idea, but I can't change the base. DB has already had the data.

Comment: create new tables using the new structure, then convert all existing data to new tables

Comment: It's difficult to explain, but I would do it if it were possible